# How to create new ActiveRecord record w enum type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

```
class Degree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  enum :degree_type, {
    high_school: 'high_school',
    associate: 'associate',
    bachelor: 'bachelor',
    masters: 'masters',
    doctoral: 'doctoral'
  }, default: 'high_school'
end
```

`u = User.last`

```
u.degrees.degree_types

{"high_school"=>"high_school",
 "associate"=>"associate",
 "bachelor"=>"bachelor",
 "masters"=>"masters",
 "doctoral"=>"doctoral"}
```

works ok..

**Try to create new record with enum**.

```
u.degrees[:high_school]
// TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

```
u.degrees['high_school']
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

```
u.degrees[1]
```

No errors, did it work?

```
u.degrees
[]
```

No.

```
u.update(degrees: :high_school)

other_array.each { |val| raise_on_type_mismatch!(val) }
```

How to create new ActiveRecord record w enum type?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason that using `update` on a user record will create a new degree record.
You can do this instead:

```
user.degrees.create(degree_type: Degree.degree_types[:high_school])
```